# How to format a RewriteRule for a GET redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

in a wordpress blog I want to redirect all the new registrations to a custom registration page.

Instead of

`www.example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=register`

I want to send them to

`www.example.com/wordpress/register`

So far I use

```
RewriteRule ^wordpress/wp-login.php?action=register$ www.example.com/wordpress/register [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't work :(

I also tried this rule;

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^action=register$
RewriteRule ^wp-login[.]php$ /register [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: Of course it will not work: 1) `RewriteRule` pattern works with path part of the URL **only**, which is `^wordpress/wp-login.php` 2) To match query string use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pattern`

Comment: thanks lazyone, but do you have any working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=register$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wordpress/wp-login.php$ http://www.example.com/wordpress/register? [L,R=301,NC]
```

1) This will redirect `http://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=register` **EXACTLY** to `http://www.example.com/wordpress/register`.

2) I suggest using 302 redirect code instead of 301 during testing, until you confirm it's working as intended (as modern browsers do cache 301 redirects which may produce confusing behaviour during testing, when you editing the rule often).

3) If you will see infinite redirect message issued by browser -- then you have conflicting rules.

Answer (score 2):

Have this rule in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/wordpress/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=register$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ register? [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! but I'd like to use the LazyOne answer since my htaccess already contains 
RewriteBase /

Comment: That's absolutely fine. I intentionally gave `RewriteBase /wordpress/`since Wordpress adds that by default in default installation.